# How can I express the probability of a Document with the probability of its text and author?

Tags: probability

Suppose I have n documents $(D_1, D_2, ...., D_n)$. The probability of $i^{th}$ documents is $P(D_i)$. Each document has a text T and an author A. How can I represent the probability of the document $D_i$ with the probability of the $T_i$ and the author $A_i$. Can I write $P(D_i) = P(A_i)*P(T_i)$?

I hope I have made my question clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The probabilities are for which events?

Comment: Unfortunately, the question is not clear.  What do you mean by the probability of the $i$th document?  You have the $n$ documents; what is $P(D_i)$ the probability of?

Comment: The probability of selecting the $i^{th}$ document from the n documents.

Comment: @BrianTung, is it even possible?

Comment: @Arpan, is it even possible?

Comment: Is *what* even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use Bayes' Theorem:

The probability of getting document $D_i$ is (reading right to left) proportional to the probability of its author, $P(A)$, times the probability of text $T$ given the text's author is $A$, times the probability of getting document $D_i$ given that the author was $A$ and its text is $T$:

$P(D_i) \propto P(D_i|T, A) P(T|A) P(A)$.

You could be clearer, though, in precisely what you're seeking.  For instance, what is the difference between a document $D$ and its text $T$?  Are they synonymous?